# SQL server Cardinality Estimation for LIKE query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, cardinality-estimates, like

I have this statistics histogram vector for my non-clustered index made on LastName column of  a table named AspNetUsers.

[image]

If I run a query as `SELECT * FROM dbo.AspNetUsers WHERE LastName = 'Baker'` it returns 6 rows as estimated rows, cause **Baker** is the **RANGE_HI_KEY** of the one of the step so the EQ_ROWS value is my Estimated rows count. Similarly, If i run a query as `SELECT * FROM dbo.AspNetUsers WHERE LastName = 'Bacilia'`, it returns 1 row as estimated rows, cause **Bacilia** fells in to 'Baker' step range, so the **AVG_RAGE_ROWS** value of that step is my estimated rows count.

Similarly, to my understanding if i do query as `SELECT * FROM dbo.AspNetUsers WHERE LastName LIKE 'Ba%'` it matches 2 steps (**Baker** and **Batagoda**), so it should return 27 + 51 (RANGE_ROWS) + 6 + 4 (EQ_ROWS) = 88. But it returns 99 rows as estimation.

How does this Cardinality Estimation is works with a LIKE Query? Does it use different formulae for estimating number of rows when doing a LIKE query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it use different formulae for estimating number of rows when
> doing a LIKE query?

Yes.

I don't know much about the gory details but see the mention of "string summary statistics" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> the statistics object contains string summary statistics to improve
> the cardinality estimates for query predicates that use the LIKE
> operator; for example, WHERE ProductName LIKE '%Bike'. String summary
> statistics are stored separately from the histogram and are created on
> the first key column of the statistics object when it is of type char,
> varchar, nchar, nvarchar, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), text, or
> ntext..

I don't have your sample data but just gave it a whirl with the [player_overviews_unindexed](https://datahub.io/sports-data/atp-world-tour-tennis-data#resource-player_overviews_unindexed) tennis player dataset.

The relevant part of the histogram for that was

```
 RANGE_HI_KEY    RANGE_ROWS     EQ_ROWS   DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS   AVG_RANGE_ROWS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Aubone            40           4                    37         1.081081
        Baker            79          12                    60         1.316667
       Barker            71           6                    55         1.290909
       Barton            46           4                    25             1.84
        Bates            26           5                    20              1.3
       Becker            45           6                    35         1.285714
```

The statistics only show definitively that the range will contain at least 170 rows (12 + 71 +  6 + 46 +  4 + 26 +  5). And at most 294 when the end ranges are taken into account.

- 79 last_name > 'Aubone' and last_name < 'Baker'
- 12 last_name = 'Baker'
- 71 last_name > 'Baker' and last_name < 'Barker'
- 6 last_name = 'Barker'
- 46 last_name > 'Barker' and last_name < 'Barton'
- 4 last_name = 'Barton'
- 26 last_name > 'Barton' and last_name < 'Bates'
- 5 last_name = 'Bates'
- 45 last_name > 'Bates' and last_name < 'Becker'

When I indexed the `last_name` column the `last_name LIKE N'Ba%'` predicate gets converted to an index seek on `last_name >= N'Ba' AND last_name < N'BB'` and residual predicate but the estimates were different.

- The estimate for `last_name >= N'Ba' AND last_name < N'BB'` was 180.525 rows.
- The estimate for `last_name LIKE N'Ba%'` was 235.935 rows
- The estimate for `LEFT(last_name, 2) = 'Ba'` was 171.317 rows.
- The actual number of rows returned was 241 rows.

For `LEFT` potentially it is just adding the `AVG_RANGE_ROWS` value of `1.316667` to that minimum of 170.

When doing the simple index range seek it looks like it just looks at the size of the range of the end histogram steps and the range of these that the query would select and does some interpolation based on that.

So there were 79 rows with `last_name > 'Aubone' and last_name < 'Baker'` in the histogram (`RANGE_ROWS`).

[image]

It estimates that `77.6735` of those 79 rows will be in the range `< 'Ba'` and only 1.3265 in the range `>= 'Ba'` - though in reality the numbers were `34` and `45` respectively.

There are lots of players with surnames (Babcock, Bahrami, Baer, Backe, Baghdatis, 7 * Baileys etc) that fall into that range but it has no way of knowing that from the histogram.

Presumably the string summary statistics does capture the distribution better here than is possible just from the histogram.

Comment: Is there a way we could see those seperate statistics stores outside the Histogram for LIKE queries in SQL server?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: Your alternate approach for the LIKE query with a range predicate and the analysis was interesting. Tried the same. Got the similar kind of difference in Seek estimate. Looks like summing the applicable steps RANGE_ROWS + EQ_ROWS is not what the SQL server engine do for that case too.

Comment: @DhanukaJayasinghe - yeah I think that is some sort of interpolation based on size of range in the histogram according to its boundary values and size of the range step that the query would select. So because `Ba` to `Bak` is on the face of it narrower than `Aub` to `Ba` SQL Server estimates only a small fraction of the 79 rows (in my case) will belong to that second range - as in execution plan screenshot at the end. In reality there are lots of players (Babcock, Bahrami, Baer, Backe, Baghdatis, 7 * Baileys etc) that fall into that range but it has no way of knowing that from the histogram

Comment: I didn't follow. Where does the 79 rows in the Execution plan?

Comment: 79 rows with `last_name > 'Aubone' and last_name < 'Baker'` in the histogram (`RANGE_ROWS`). It estimates that `77.6735` of those will be in the range `< 'Ba'` and only `1.3265` in the range `>= 'Ba'` - though in reality the numbers were 34 and 45 respectively

Comment: I'm kind of lost with the explanation right now. I'm not sure how the `LastName >= 'Ba' and LastName < 'Bb'` is relates with the explanation on `last_name > 'Aubone' and last_name < 'Baker'` and the execution plan.

Comment: Based purely on the histogram we know that there are definitely at least 170 rows matching `Ba%`. We also have a group of 79 rows at the start - which all we know about is that they are in the range `> 'Aubone' and  < 'Baker'`  so anywhere between `0` and `79` of these could match and we have a similar group of 45 at the end in the range `last_name > 'Bates' and last_name < 'Becker'` so anywhere between 0 and 45 of those could start with "Ba"

Comment: The estimate for `last_name >= N'Ba' AND last_name < N'BB'`  was `180.525` rows so SQL Server only estimates `10.525` rows out of the potential `124` in these ambiguous ranges will match - which is quite a big underestimate and worse than the string statistics managed. This was just looking into that. And for the initial chunk of 79 rows it looks like it assumes most of them will belong to the group before the range `Ba` starts

Comment: That make sense now. Went bit off from the original question on how the LIKE query cardinality estimation works. But the answer was very insightful on understanding more on how the cardinality estimation works. So upvoting the answer. Thanks mate!

Comment: My answer to that question is just it uses "string summary statistics" - that as far as I know aren't documented any further than the quote given from BOL or are available for us to look at. The only additional thing I have to add on that is I believe I read somewhere it uses [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Yes string statistics are based on tries